# Limit of trig function raised to trig function

Tags: calculus

I need help on evaluating this limit:

$\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{\sin{x}}{x})^{\frac{1}{1-\cos{x}}}$. So far I have tried setting the limit to L and taking the ln of both sides. So $\ln{L}=\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{1}{1-\cos{x}}\ln{(\frac{\sin{x}}{x})})$. I then tried using L'Hopital on the indeterminate 0/0 to no luck. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{\sin{x}}{x})^{\frac{1}{1-\cos{x}}}$$

$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln (\frac{\sin{x}}{x})}{1-\cos{x}}$$

$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\ln (\frac{\sin{x}}{x})}{\frac{d}{dx}(1-\cos{x})}$$

$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\ln (\sin x)-\ln x)}{\sin{x}}$$

$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{\tan x}-\frac{1}{x}}{\sin{x}}$$

$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\tan x}{x\tan x\sin{x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use series expansion, consider $$A=\left(\frac{\sin{(x)}}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\cos{(x)}}}\implies \log(A)=\frac{1}{1-\cos{(x)}}\log\left(\frac{\sin{(x)}}{x}\right)$$ and use $$\sin{(x)}=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ $$\frac{\sin{(x)}}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$\log\left(\frac{\sin{(x)}}{x}\right)=-\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x^4}{180}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$1-\cos(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$\log(A)=\frac{-\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x^4}{180}+O\left(x^6\right) }{\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right) }=\frac {-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{x^2}{180}+O\left(x^4\right) }{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{24}+O\left(x^4\right)}$$ which already shows the limit for $\log(A)$.

If you want to go further, use  the long division (or Taylor series again) to get $$\log(A)=-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{7 x^2}{180}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ and $$A=e^{\log(A)}=e^{-\frac{1}{3}}\left(1-\frac{7 x^2}{180} \right)+O\left(x^4\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

It is even a good approximation of the function. If you use $x=\frac \pi 6$ the exact value would be $$A=\left(\frac{3}{\pi }\right)^{2 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}\approx 0.708768$$ while the truncated series would give $$\frac{6480-7 \pi ^2}{6480 \sqrt[3]{e}}\approx 0.708892$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$((1+\frac{sin x-x}x)^{\frac x{\sin x-x}})^{\frac{sin x-x}{x(1-\cos x)}}$$

Now  use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion) for the exponent.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Note that $\ds{\,\mrm{sinc}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}}$ is an *even*  function such that $\ds{\,\mrm{sinc}'}$ is an *odd* function, $\ds{\,\mrm{sinc}''}$ is an $\ds{\color{#f00}{even}}$ function, $\ds{\,\mrm{sinc}'''}$ is an *odd* function and so on.
>   
>   $\ds{\,\mrm{sinc}\pars{x} =
> \left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
> \ds{\sin\pars{x} \over x} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x \not = 0}
> \\
> \ds{1} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x = 0}
> \end{array}\right.}$

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0}\bracks{\sin\pars{x} \over x}^{1/\bracks{1-\cos\pars{x}}} & =
\exp\pars{\lim_{x \to 0}{\ln\pars{\mrm{sinc}\pars{x}} \over 1 - \cos\pars{x}}} =
\exp\pars{\lim_{x \to 0}{{\mrm{sinc}'\pars{x}} \over \sin\pars{x}\,\mrm{sinc}\pars{x}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\exp\pars{\lim_{x \to 0}{{\mrm{sinc}'\pars{x}} \over \sin\pars{x}}} =
\exp\pars{\lim_{x \to 0}{{\mrm{sinc}''\pars{x}} \over \cos\pars{x}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\exp\pars{\lim_{x \to 0}{\mrm{sinc}''\pars{x}}} =
\exp\pars{\lim_{x \to 0}\bracks{-\,{1 \over 3} + {x^{2} \over 10} + \,\mrm{O}\pars{x^{4}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\expo{-1/3}} \approx 0.7165
\end{align}